# CSS Max-width 100% Responsive design

Tags: html, css, image

In my general CSS styles,  I declare a `(max-width 100%)` rule for all images.

This means my images will become flexible and scale with their container, but never go beyond their native size.

When the screen reaches > 800px I use a media query to float the image right and the paragraph text left (image and paragraph are now side by side).

However - When I float the image to the right, I reduce its size by 50%... I target the image and apply a CSS rule of `width: 50%;`

However the image is still flexible... how does this work? I would assume the `width: 50%;` rule would override the `max-width: 100%;` rule?

Does `width: 50%;` change the size of the image container? Therefore the `max-width: 100%;` rule still applies?

I hope the above makes sense?

Comment: Please use http://lorempixel.com and http://jsbin.com to make a demo for your case.

Answer (score 0):

When in conflict, the `max-width` and `max-height` properties will override `width` and `height` properties, so your assumption was backward.

Comment: max-width and width don't exclude each other, setting width in % gives it a responsive value; if the container changes so does the value of 50%

Comment: thanks, Just to clarify. 

when I set width:50% (the image halves in size) BUT will still SCALE when the page size increases  

Does this mean the width rule applies FIRST and then get's overridden by the max-width rule when the page stretches?




Brilliant, thanks for your help .. Just to clarify. 

when I set width:50% (the image halves in size) BUT will still SCALE when the page size increases ?  

Does this mean .. I apply the width rule  and then this get's overridden when I stretch the screen by the max-width rule?  (regardless of order the rules are placed)

Comment: @maioman Sorry, I was hasty! I've edited the post for more accuracy. Unfortunately, I see in my haste I somewhat misread the question.

Comment: @user4322189 If you have `width: 50%;` on an image, it will be 50% as wide as its containing element. `width: 50%` is a responsive declaration, because percentages are a calculated value in response to a paint or re-paint event. Every time the page is re-painted, percentage values in CSS are recalculated by the browser. This is the case regardless of whether you have a `max-width` rule declared anywhere.

Comment: @user4322189 The fact that you have `max-width: 100%;` set means, as Jeff stated above in his answer, if your image somehow grows wider than 100% of its containing element, then `max-width: 100%;` will kick in and override the `width: 50%;` rule. Think of it like this: if you are counting to 1000 one number at a time, starting at one, you will keep adding 1 in order to fulfill your task. The limit of 1000 doesn't affect the repeated task of +1 that you perform over and over again... **until** you get to 1000. Once you get there, you don't do +1 anymore.

Answer (score 0):

As maioman said. These properties don't override each other, they work in tandem. If a width of 50% is greater than the image at 100%, max-width will apply. If that's not your preference, you can override the max-width in your float class:

```
img.float-right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: none;
}
```